# Mysql query to join two table and group by matching id

Tags: php, mysql

Am trying to group user orders by the order id, but am not getting it right i know this will be first get done in the SQL query then organise it well in `PHP` and `HTML` but i don't know how to get it done.

**orderinfo**

```
oid  | userid  | total  | payid
-----|---------|--------|----------
oi10 | peter   | 650    | VCC-100
oi12 | john    | 30     | VCC-500
oi15 | peter   | 60     | COD-500
```

**itemorder**

```
pid | ioid  | userid  | price  | qty | itemname
----| ------|---------|--------|-----|-----------
p10 | oi10  | peter   | 200    | 1   | lexus
p20 | oi10  | peter   | 150    | 1   | Toyota
p15 | oi10  | peter   | 300    | 1   | Myvi
p66 | oi15  | peter   | 25     | 2   | BMW
p67 | oi15  | peter   | 10     | 1   | Saga
p67 | oi12  | john    | 10     | 3   | Saga
```

**My current Code**

```
$handler->prepare('
    SELECT * FROM itemorder io
    LEFT JOIN orderinfo oi
    ON io.oid = oi.ioid
    WHERE io.userid = 'peter' 
    GROUP BY io.oid
    ORDER BY oi.pid DESC
');
$handler->execute();
$RecentOrder = $handler->getAll();
$handler->free();
    if(!empty($RecentOrder)){
        foreach($RecentOrder as $row){

        }
    }
```

**Expected Result**

I want the result to be sorted according to the `order id` all item that has same order id will be listed (list according to order id).

```
oid: oi10
  --------
    lexus
    Toyota
    Myvi
---------------------
oid: oi15 
   --------
    BMW
    Saga
```

Comment: Why do you add this character in front of the IDs?

Comment: @CagatayUlubay i think one can use `INT` or `VARCHAR` as product ID or Order ID? But i just use the `p` and `o` to make it understandable for people that will offer help

Comment: If ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is disabled, a MySQL extension to the standard SQL use of GROUP BY permits the select list, HAVING condition, or ORDER BY list to refer to nonaggregated columns even if the columns are not functionally dependent on GROUP BY columns. This causes MySQL to accept the preceding query. In this case, the server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate, which is probably not what you want https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: This naming policy may become wearying, eieio.

Comment: Is there a typo(or few) io.oid doesn't exist nor does oi.pid and what purpose does the join serve you don't seem to need anything from orderinfo.

Comment: And don't store 'p' and 'oi'

Comment: @Strawberry why? please tell me why int is better

Comment: int is usually faster and stores less bytes. As far as I understood the indexing will be easier too.

Comment: That's not what I said. The data type makes little difference (although some, maybe). It's the redundancy, and lack of normalisation which is problematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired output can be retrieved with just `ORDER BY`.

```
SELECT *
...
ORDER BY oi.oid DESC, io.pid DESC
```

And then do the specific formatting in PHP. Easiest way is probably to remember the order_id of the last row.

```
$lastOrderId = null;
foreach ($result as $row) {
    if ($lastOrderId != $row['oid']) {
        echo 'oid: ' . $row['oid'] . PHP_EOL;
        echo '  -----------' . PHP_EOL;
    }
    echo '     ' . $row['itemname'] . PHP_EOL;

    $lastOrderId = $row['oid'];
}
```

Comment: Except of course, the OP should select the columns they actually want.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
SELECT io.ioid,GROUP_CONCAT("",io.itemname) as order_items FROM itemorder as io
        LEFT JOIN orderinfo as oi
        ON io.ioid = oi.oid
        WHERE io.userid = 'peter' 
        GROUP BY io.ioid
    ORDER BY io.pid DESC
```

Please not the columns on which join is done.

Then in PHP you can use `explode` function to get the array of names for each order.

Hope this helps!